# Copy a Filtered Table

Tags: excel, vba, copy, autofilter, listobject

Trying to copy a filtered table and paste the results to the bottom of another table.

```
With RollupWeekSheet
   sh1Col = .Range("Table1").Cells(1).Column
   LastRollupWeekRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, sh1Col).End(xlUp).Row
End With


Dim ComboWeekTable As ListObject
Set ComboWeekTable = ComboWeekSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

Dim RollupTimeStamp As Date
RollupTimeStamp = RollupWeekSheet.Range("B3").Value

With ComboWeekTable
.Range.AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=">" & RollupTimeStamp
.DataBodyRange.Copy
End With

With RollupWeekSheet
.Cells(LastRollupWeekRow + 1, sh1Col).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
ComboWeekTable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End With`

With ComboWeekSheet
If .AutoFilterMode Then
.AutoFilterMode = False
End If
End With
```

It keeps highlighting the ".Autofilter" located under my "With ComboWeekTable" line and saying "Invalid use of property", but I don't know why.  Please help.

Comment: Try to record macro with your desired actions, and see, if it even possible. Then generated VBA code

Comment: Try `With ComboWeekTable.Range`

Comment: I changed to ComboWeekTable.Range.  It is now highlighting the entire row below that ( ".Autofilter.Rang.Copy" ) and saying "Object variable with block variable not set".  I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Are there any visible rows at that point?

Answer (score 2):

It's a case of getting to the correct properties of the ListObject

Assuming you want just the filtered data rows (and not the header):

```
With ComboWeekTable
    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=">" & RollupTimeStamp
    .DataBodyRange.Copy
End With
```

Unlike `SpecialCells` this still works if the filter returns no rows (no error, doesn't paste anything), so no need for error trapping

Demo

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lo As ListObject

    Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
    Set ws2 = ws1.Parent.Worksheets(ws1.Index + 1)
    Set lo = ws1.ListObjects(1)

    If lo.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then lo.Range.AutoFilter
    lo.ShowAutoFilterDropDown = True
    With lo
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=2"
        If Application.Aggregate(3, 5, lo.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange) > 0 Then 'Count All, ignoring hidden rows
            .DataBodyRange.Copy
            ws2.Range("D5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
        lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData ' clear filter
    End With
End Sub
```

Before running Demo

[image]

After running Demo

[image]

Comment: This eliminated my errors, but it is copying the entire table body range, not just the filtered rows of the table body range.

Comment: @Dave F  it worked for me.  Added Demo to illustrate

Comment: @ chrisneilsen   Idk. It works perfectly for me as long as there are filtered rows to be copied; it copies and pastes those rows perfectly, just like in your demo. But when there are no filtered rows showing, it copies and pastes the entire table. I'm very new to VBA and maybe I'm not applying something properly to my exact code. I've updated the original post to show my updated code with your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED to match your setup. This worked for me in testing:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim rngPaste As Range, ComboWeekTable As ListObject
    Dim RollupTimeStamp As Date

    'find the paste position
    With RollupWeekSheet.ListObjects("Table2").DataBodyRange
       Set rngPaste = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Cells(1).Offset(1, 0)
    End With

    Set ComboWeekTable = ComboWeekSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

    RollupTimeStamp = RollupWeekSheet.Range("B3").Value

    With ComboWeekTable.DataBodyRange
        .AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=">" & RollupTimeStamp

        On Error Resume Next '<< ignore run-time error if no rows visible
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy rngPaste
        On Error GoTo 0      '<< stop ignoring errors

        .AutoFilter
    End With

    ComboWeekTable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1

End Sub
```

Comment: The top bit of code works.  Thanks!  But I'm new to VBA and don't understand where to place the second bit of code that eliminates errors if no rows are found.  Can you please tell me exactly where to place these 3 lines that eliminate run-time errors?

Comment: I am new to this and can barely make heads or tails out of my own code.  I do not understand how to translate your `Range("A15")` into the actual code that i have shown in my original post.  I'm copying from table ComboWeekTable and am trying to paste to the bottom of RollupWeekTable.  And there is already some code in there, which i don't completely understand, to bump me down to the next available line (`LastRollupWeekRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, sh1Col).End(xlUp).Row`). 
 Please help me understand how to cross-reference your "A15" to my code.