# VBA copy mutlipe rows that meet criteria to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I really don't understand much VBA, so be patient with me.

I have a list of people assigned to a specific flight (LEGID) and I want to copy those people (Worksheet pax)  to a specific cell in another worksheet (temp - cell b15), but it doesn't work.

This data table is a query report from salesforce.

```
Sub pax()

   Dim LastRow As Long
   Dim i As Long, j As Long
   Dim legid As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

legid = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("SelReq").Value

Debug.Print legid


   'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
   With Worksheets("pax")
      LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   End With

'   MsgBox (LastRow)
   'first row number where you need to paste values in temp'
   With Worksheets("temp")
      j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   End With

   For i = 1 To LastRow
       With Worksheets("pax")
           If .Cells(i, 1).Value = legid Then
               .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("temp").Range("a" & j)
               j = j + 1
           End If
       End With
   Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get an error or nothing is being copied?

Comment: If the data is stored in a table, In my opinion you will want to use the `ListObject` instead looping through a range.

Comment: No error. Just don't do anything. - @Warcupine

Comment: How can I do that? @ZackE

Comment: Take a look at the second answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56469221/copy-a-filtered-table)

Comment: sorry. I can't see how it works. I suck. can you help me do it?

Comment: is `legid = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("SelReq").Value` a single cell or is it a range of cells with names?

Comment: it's a cell. the refect a value like this:
https://ibb.co/wwH1XRZ

Comment: Take a look at the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to just get the names copied over.  You can use this; however you will need to update your sheet names and ranges if they are named ranges.  This code looks at a specific cell for a value on Sheet3 then if that value matches a value from a range on Sheet1 it will place the values from Column B on Sheet1 into Sheet2

```
Sub Test()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim legid As String


    With Sheet1
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    With Sheet2
        j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With

    legid = Sheet3.Range("A1")

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        For Each cell In Sheet1.Range("A" & i)
            If cell.Value = legid Then
                Sheet2.Range("A" & j) = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next cell
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @zack e. Your code wasn't working on my excel. so i try to copy a portion of the tablees to a new excel and my code and your code is working. so my question is. the code doesn't work on query tables?